# Chrome extension doesn't work first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that adds a custom button beside the "like" button in facebook.

The problem is that when I launch facebook that button doesn't appear and when I refresh the page it appears.

It's a basic jQuery script:

```
$(".like_link").after("...MY BUTTON...");
```

I also tried to put an alert("extension works") function to see when the extension is loaded and when it doesn't. So the problem is not of the button, it's a problem of the extension itself.

I tried one more thing, I set the extension to work on all the websites (`*://*.*` in manifest.json). In all the websites it worked all the time, and in facebook I had to refresh every page after I launched it.

jQuery id LOADED into my extension. My manifest.json file:

```
{
"name": "Custom button",
"version": "0.1",
"description": "Add a custom button beside the like button!",
"content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": ["*://facebook.com/*"], //or *://*/*
    "css": ["style.css"],
    "js": ["jquery-1.7.2.min.js","script.js"]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: did you check the class of updated button to see if there is a difference after page refresh?

Comment: Yes, I also tried to put an alert() function to see when the extension is loaded and when it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the developer console?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the question, take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `"matches": ["*://*.facebook.com/*"]` (inserted asterisk before `facebook.com`)

Comment: jQuery is DO loaded, because I've loaded it in my extension!

Comment: Ok, then may be it's the `matches` key. I've tried it using the changed `matches` property from my answer, that worked here.